# When sharing a Dropbox folder, whose quota is "billed"?

Tags: sharing, dropbox

I shared a Dropbox folder with another user.  Who "owns" the files there?  Whose quota will this come out of?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm afraid it comes out of *both* of your quotas: https://www.dropbox.com/help/59

Comment: It's nice that they explain the reasoning behind this.